# Reset à declaração "padding" em CSS

Tags: css, css-padding

Algumas *frameworks*, como o caso do [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) fazem uso de declarações base em CSS para uniformizar o comportamento geral em determinados elementos.

Neste caso, o `padding`:

```
td, th {
    padding: 0;
}
```

O problema é que ao gerar conteúdo a partir de um editor [*WYSIWYG*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG), algumas definições são conflituosas com a *framework* onde esse conteúdo vai ser inserido:

```html
<table border="1" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width:100%">
  <!-- ... -->
</table>
```

Essencialmente, o atributo `cellpadding` não vai produzir o efeito desejado uma vez que a *framework* vai subscrever o mesmo com a declaração em cima apresentada.

## Pergunta

Como fazer *reset* à declaração de `padding` de forma a que num local especifico o atributo `cellpadding` possa ser utilizado pelo navegador ?

```
td, th {
    padding: auto; /* incorreto pois não existe, mas reflete o que se pretende */
}
```

Comment: Olá zuul's, na minha opinião os melhores editores são os que usam iframe, justamente para evitar este tipo de conflito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o *initial*

```
td, th {
 padding: initial; }
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding.asp